# Which one is preferred, A teaching assistant or a substitute teacher

Tags: job-search, salary

I had a quick search on both job positions, however I am still not sure which one is better on an overall basis. Though a TA job is more stable, but it seems like being a labor worker than being actual educator. The salary is lower as well. On the other side, A substitute teacher seems to be paid hourly and not as stable as a TA job. This is at least my understand based on the Internet and relatively based on cases in US (though I am far away from that region.)

Is there a solid comparison between these two?

Comment: This isn't really an answerable question here because this is a pros/cons question. You already appear to understand the distinction between both roles;  which one you should take is your own personal choice depending on your circumstances and needs.

Comment: In Canada, substitute teacher is a type of teaching position for which you have to have a teaching license whereas a TA is a completely different career path which does not require any post secondary education.  From the teachers that I know TAs fill a role in the school but are not viewed as a kind of teacher.  Better can only be defined by you.  If your overall goal is to be a regular teacher then TA doesn't progress that goal.  If your goal is to put food on the table only you can decide how important stability is.

Comment: @JoeStrazzereThat is about right except I have a chance to apply for either at a school and do not know which one I should go for. I must say I have no teaching experience but the school I would like to apply does not require it for substitute teachers. In addition, I am not sure if being a substitute teacher has a better publicity or being a TA, or if the future career is brighter in which direction.

Comment: IMO the best substitutes are ones with plenty of experience. I'm not sure what country you are in however in the UK students will shred a substitute to pieces if they think they will be an easy ride. Teachers assistant wont have to deal with discipline on such an extreme level.

Answer (score 3):

In my part of the world they are very different positions.

A substitute teacher is a fill-in. They are typically called in at the last minute due to a full-time teacher being sick, or otherwise away from the classroom for the day. Substitute teachers are on call, and may or may not have any work on any given day. In some schools substitutes must have similar credentials as regular teachers. In other schools, those credential requirements can be waived. Substitute teachers are usually paid a fixed amount per day of work, with no benefits.

A teaching assistant is a full-time position. They are a regular part of the classroom staff. They help the teacher with classroom activities and activities outside the classroom, but aren't required to have the same educational credentials as a teacher. Teaching assistants are typically paid hourly or salary, often with benefits.

In my part of the world, the actual requirements and remuneration for each position are specified locally - often by the specific school.

Which role would be better for you depends on your individual needs, goals, and background. There's no real way to generalize it.

Answer (score 1):

A substitute teacher is not more of an 'actual educator' it's someone who treads water while the 'real' teacher is unavailable. You don't design and implement workflow or get to know the students well (very important educator roles).

Teachers Aide is more stable, gives better experience and is a solid foundation for advancement within an institution.

Substitute teacher pays better but has no real safety net.

If you don't have the experience to know which suits you best, you should go for the Aide position, there is less accountability and more guidance. Possibly most importantly you interact with and get to impact on the same group of students for a year which builds critical skills.

Comment: Some substitutes do long term jobs when teachers are out for maternity leave or illness or family emergency. So yes some substitutes get to know their students and are sometimes actual educators. We certainly got to know the limited number of subs in our school system too even if they taught history one day and gym the next. It is however a job fora  retiree or someone who is looking for temp money until they land a permanent position. Very few people substitute for years without being retired.

Comment: @HLGEM there are always exceptions